# discord.py - Is possible save member commands?

Tags: discord.py, command

Is possible to save member commands in a channel or file?
When a member execute a bot command to send in channel:

`member test executed !testcmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are possible. Here you have an example in where the logs are sent to a guild channel. Adapting the code to save them in a file should be easy.

The idea is quite simple, can be executed in 3 steps:

1. Define the channel where you want the logs to be sent to
2. Define a function to send the logs to the channel you chose
3. At the end of each command, call the function defined in step 2

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Change intents if needed
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
TOKEN = "Your Token"

guild = None        # The guild you want your bot to send the logs to
channel = None      # The channel of the guild you want your bot to send the logs to
guild_id = 123456789
channel_id = 987654321

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global guild, channel, guild_id, channel_id
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    print("Logged")

# For sending the logs 
async def command_logs(ctx : commands.Context):
    await channel.send(f"member **{ctx.author}** executed **{ctx.command.name}**")

@bot.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx : commands.Context):
    # Your command's code
    await ctx.send("Test")
    # ...

    # Send the logs at the end
    await command_logs(ctx)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [@after_invoke](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Command.after_invoke) command's decorator to call the function defined in step 2:

```
@bot.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx : commands.Context):
    # Your command's code
    await ctx.send("Test")
    # ...

@test.after_invoke
async def test_after_invoke(ctx : commands.Context):
    await command_logs(ctx)
```